# Lamda expression in java

Tags: java

Are there any difference between them?

1. (x, y) -> x + y;
2. (x) -> (y) -> x + y;
3. x -> y -> x + y;

If these are identical expression, are there any reasons why they are different?

Comment: 2 and 3 are identical, 1 is different. You can *try* them and figure out how and why they are different.

Answer (score 1):

A lambda expression always implements a [functional interface](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces) in Java.

The functional interface determines the types of the parameters and the return value of the lambda expression.

You can see that lambda expression 1 is different from 2 and 3, because they have different numbers of parameters.

Assuming that `x` and `y` are `int` values, the first one would match interface [`java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/IntBinaryOperator.html):

```
IntBinaryOperator expr1 = (x, y) -> x + y;
```

Now, look carefully at number 2 and 3. What you really have there is a lambda expression with one parameter `x` which returns a lambda expression with one parameter `y`.

That would match, for example, interface `IntFunction<IntUnaryOperator>`:

```
IntFunction<IntUnaryOperator> expr2 = x -> y -> x + y;
```

An `IntFunction` is a function that takes some value and that returns an `int`.

In this case the value that the `IntFunction` takes is an `IntUnaryOperator`, which is a function that takes an `int` and returns an `int`.

The `IntUnaryOperator` is the inner lambda: `y -> x + y`

The `IntFunction` is the outer lambda: `x -> (y -> x + y)`

Whether you put parentheses around the `x` and `y` in lambda expressions 2 and 3 doesn't matter.